# Postgresql Connection Timed out

Tags: centos, postgresql, database-connection

when I am connecting to psql on remote server

```
>psql -h {hostname}
psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060). Is the server running on host "{hostname}" (194.58.98.133) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

On server:

```
netstat -nlp | grep 5432
tcp   0 0 0.0.0.0:5432   0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  29609/postmaster
tcp        0      0 :::5432  :::*  LISTEN      29609/postmaster
unix  2   [ ACC ]  STREAM   LISTENING 2107633273 29609/postmaster   /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

there is not iptables on server. Pinging the server is successful.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Intermediate firewall somewhere? Use `tcptraceroute` (or on newer platforms, normal traceroute in tcp mode)

Answer (score 6):

I was getting this kind of error when my `pg_hba.conf` or AWS security groups have not been configured properly. There are plenty of docs about how to resolve this. For example, you can check the below, quoted from this [link](http://www.revsys.com/writings/postgresql/errors.html#cannot-connect-remote)

> *Error:* psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "192.168.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>
> *Common Cause:* The postmaster or PostgreSQL's server daemon process is not running or configured incorrectly.
>
> When you receive this error most of the time it is due to not having PostgreSQL configured to allow TCP/IP connections or at least not connections from your particular workstation. If you have verified that `postmaster` is indeed running on the host you are trying to connect to then here is a list of common causes to this problem:
>
> - `postgresql.conf` not setup to allow TCP/IP connections. You'll want to look at the `listen_address` configuration parameter.
> - `postgresql.conf` is not setup to allow connections on a non-standard port number. To determine this look at the `port` configuration option.
> - authentication rules in PostgreSQL's access configuration file (`pg_hba.conf`) are not setup to allow either your uses or IP address to connect to that database. See [the official documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/client-authentication.html) for more information on setting up your `pg_hba.conf` properly.
> - ensure that there are no firewalls, such as `iptables` that are keeping your local system from even establishing a connection to the remote host

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at *postgresql.conf*. To allow connections from everywhere you have to set the *listen_adresses* to *:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

the *pg_hba.conf* should have an entry like that, to allow connection from your network:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             192.168.190.0/24        md5
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case as I had an AWS RDS managed instance the problem was a security group rule.

Adding an inbound rule to allow traffic from my PC allowed the connection. For further details please reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70337387/4725074

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your firewall settings? Try to allow 5432 port connection.
E.g. Ubuntu ufw: **`sudo ufw allow 5432`**